# Getting error "Single row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update fct_capital 
     set LINE_ITEM_ID = 
          (select line_item_id 
               from 
                    dim_line_item_capital 
               where LINE_ITEM_DESC
                     in
                         (select CUSTOMER_FIELD7 
                          from fct_capital 
                          where 
                             partition_key like '20180930%' 
                             and STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID=18544
                          )
           ) 
where 
partition_key 
    like 
     '20180930%' and STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID=18544 ;
```

Getting error while trying to execute above  sql code, Have tried using max and distinct selected columns but still no use.

Comment: Looks like inner SQL query returns more than one row. Try running inner query and see how many rows it returns.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.

Comment: The inner query is working fine as it was getting more than one record...but when I'm using it has whole then I'm getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend a correlated subquery:

```
update fct_capital
    set LINE_ITEM_ID = (select lic.line_item_id
                        from dim_line_item_capital lic
                        where lic.LINE_ITEM_DESC = fct_capital.CUSTOMER_FIELD7
                       )
    where partition_key like '20180930%' and 
          STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID = 18544 ;
```

You may still get duplicates.  If so, you have duplicates in `line_item_desc`.  You can find these with a query:

```
select lic.line_item_desc
from dim_line_item_capital lic
group by lic.line_item_desc
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I have more than one records, Which i am trying to validate for only ID 18544.

Answer (score 0):

If everything in your query is fine then this must be the possible solution for your query.

```
 GO

 update fct_capital 
 set LINE_ITEM_ID = (select top 1 line_item_id from dim_line_item_capital where 
 LINE_ITEM_DESC in (select CUSTOMER_FIELD7 from fct_capital where 
 partition_key like '20180930%' and STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID=18544 )) 
 where partition_key like '20180930%' and STRESS_TESTING_SCENARIO_ID=18544 ;

 GO
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time, This was what i am missing tried using distinct still it has multiple rows as outcome. Let  me check your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your update statement looks like:

```
update fct_capital 
set line_item_id = ( <subquery> )
where <conditions>;
```

So for a row in `fct_capital` that meet the conditions the subquery is run to find out which value to set `line_item_id` to. We expect this query to return a value like 1234 or 5678 or whatever, just one single value to update the `fct_capital` row with.

Now let's see, what the subquery produces. First we have:

```
select customer_field7 
from fct_capital 
where partition_key like '20180930%' 
and stress_testing_scenario_id = 18544
```

I don't know whether this returns one or more rows. Anyway, you are prepared for both cases, because you use `IN` on this query, i.e. you can deal with a set of values. Let's say it returns the values 'A', 'B', and 'C'. Then we have:

```
select line_item_id 
from dim_line_item_capital 
where line_item_desc in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

This query is supposed to return the one value we need to update our `fct_capital` row. Obviously, though, it returns several values (which can be expected when we look for multiple `line_item_desc`) and the DBMS raises an error.

You must change the subquery to return exactly one `line_item_id`. So far the subquery is completely independent from the row you are updating. That is possible. You'd update all rows matching the condition with the same value. This could be done by picking one of the `line_item_desc`, e.g. the greatest:

```
select max(line_item_id)
from dim_line_item_capital 
where line_item_desc in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Or you want the subquery to be related to the updated row. You do this by accessing `fct_capital` columns in the subquery.

```
update fct_capital 
set line_item_id =
(
  select line_item_id 
  from dim_line_item_capital lic 
  where lic.line_item_desc = fct_capital.customer_field7
)
where partition_key like '20180930%'
and stress_testing_scenario_id = 18544;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response.